# Spring expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a trouble with this Autowire:

```
@Controller
public class ChiusuraController {

    @Autowired
    private ChiusuraProvider chiusuraProvider;
}
```

with this bean:

```
@Service @Transactional
public class ChiusuraProvider extends ThreadProvider {


    public void run() {}
}
```

that extends

```
public abstract class ThreadProvider extends Thread implements InitializingBean, Runnable, DisposableBean {
...
}
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chiusuraController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cinebot.service.ChiusuraProvider com.cinebot.web.controller.ChiusuraController.chiusuraProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.cinebot.service.ChiusuraProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I saw that I did not get this error if I remove  **extends ThreadProvider**  of autowired class, but I really need ThreadProvider abstract class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there is an interface anywhere in the ThreadProvider hierarchy try putting the name of the Interface as the type of your service provider, eg. if you have say this structure:

```
public class ThreadProvider implements CustomInterface{
...
}
```

Then in your controller try this:

```
@Controller
public class ChiusuraController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomInterface chiusuraProvider;
}
```

The reason why this is happening is, in your first case when you DID NOT have `ChiusuraProvider` extend `ThreadProvider` Spring probably was underlying creating a CGLIB based proxy for you(to handle the @Transaction).

When you DID extend from `ThreadProvider` assuming that ThreadProvider extends some interface, Spring in that case creates a Java Dynamic Proxy based Proxy, which would appear to be an implementation of that interface instead of being of `ChisuraProvider` type.

If you absolutely need to use `ChisuraProvider` you can try AspectJ as an alternative or force CGLIB based proxy in the case with ThreadProvider also this way:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Here is some more reference on this from the Spring Reference site: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-aop-spring.html#classic-aop-pfb

Comment: What if my class implements multiple interface?

Comment: Wait... you simply saved my life. I used the annotation version @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) . Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You should put this line in your application context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cinebot.service" />
```

[Read more about *Automatically detecting classes and registering bean definitions* in documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-scanning-autodetection).

Comment: I added this line where ChiusuraProvider is included in package com.cinebot.service and ThreadProvider  is NOT included in that package... but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you tried @BijuKunjummen's answer (using AOP scoped proxy, remember to add CGLIB dependency)?