# Spring Framework - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, spring-mvc

I am going to be confused. I am trying to get Hibernate work with Spring, I can not get rid of a BeanCreationException. Please help me. I am new to Spring (and also Hibernate).

The problem is caused in a controller, having a private attribute userService which is annotated with @Autowired.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.aerts.service.UserService com.aerts.controller.TestController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aerts.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I am really confused, please help me somebody.

Here is my root-context.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">



<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.aerts.controller">
</context:component-scan>


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:application.properties" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://....."/>
    <property name="username" value="....."/>
    <property name="password" value="....."/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>
    </bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Here is my User.java

```
    package com.aerts.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(name="birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }
    public void setBirthdate(Date age) {
        this.birthdate = age;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname.trim();
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname.trim();
    }
}
```

My UserDaoImpl:

```
package com.aerts.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.aerts.domain.User;


@Service
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);      
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User")
                .list();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUser(int id) {
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                User.class, id);
        if (user != null) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);

    }

}
```

And my UserServiceImpl:

```
package com.aerts.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.aerts.dao.UserDao;
import com.aerts.domain.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return userDao.listUser();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(int id) {
        userDao.removeUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me, i am going to be desperate...

Comment: I believe you're scanning only the `controller` package, your service class is outside that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the service class package to the `component-scan` base-package list in the application context file

```
<context:component-scan 
    base-package="
        com.aerts.controller
        com.aerts.service">
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reimeus!!!! You made me so happy, you can't believe! If I could vote you up I did! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expertise in spring but I assume that you have a problem with your service, if you use an interface you should inject ut and not your class...

see this track...

[Spring expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332289/spring-expected-at-least-1-bean-which-qualifies-as-autowire-candidate-for-this-d)